# Doing Sound effects, How the atmos pan techniques are using for getting good image?

Tags: sound-design, mixing

How the pan techniques are using in atmos. what is basic logic in that. can you explain your work flow in that doing sound design. for example in a rain scene do we use the track in top speakers. please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Your English isn't great but I think I get the drift. Not sure what you mean by top speakers but I'm guessing (since you have to ask) that your not mixing in 7.1 or anything silly. But basically atmos must be recorded in at least stereo so that you have a proper stereo image. Atmos tracks are a stereo effect. So it would just be a case of recording or sourcing rainy weather thats been recorded with a stereo mic then just drop it on a stereo track panned hard left and right. In surround, you would need the sound recorded in surround with 5 mics then drop it on a surround track.

Atmos should never be mono it will never sound right in a mix.

Comment: thank you Melloj & sorry for my english. 

yes now I'm working on an atoms film, this is my first atmos film. i didn't know, how this atmos features want to use. (top speakers i meant by top surrounds) @Melloj